# How can I solve http_port 3129 intercept with squid?

Tags: freebsd, squid, nat

My system:

```
uname -a
FreeBSD server.local.jmorenov.com.co 9.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE #0 r243825: Tue Dec  4 09:23:10 UTC 2012     root@farrell.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

pkg info | grep squid
squid-3.2.7                    HTTP Caching Proxy
```

I have this configuration in squid.conf:

```
http_port 3128 accel vhost allow-direct # OK
http_port 3129 intercept                # Does not work
icp_port 0
```

When I tried with:

```
http_port 3129 intercept
```

By switch line on ipnat.rules. In access log appears:

```
2013/01/09 00:46:03 kid1| IPF (IPFilter) NAT open failed: (13) Permission denied
2013/01/09 00:46:03 kid1| BUG #3329: Orphan Comm::Connection: local=127.0.0.1:3129 remote=192.168.1.129:51595 FD 24 flags=33
2013/01/09 00:46:03 kid1| NOTE: 1 Orphans since last started.
```

/var/log/squid/cache.log

```
2013/02/08 09:02:33 kid1| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2013/02/08 09:02:33 kid1| Accepting reverse-proxy HTTP Socket connections at local=127.0.0.1:3128 remote=[::] FD 33 flags=9
2013/02/08 09:02:33 kid1| Accepting NAT intercepted HTTP Socket connections at local=127.0.0.1:3129 remote=[::] FD 34 flags=41
```

My /etc/ipnat.rules:

```
root@server:/root # cat /etc/ipnat.rules
# em0  = External NIC
# bge0 = Internal NIC

map em0 0/0                     -> 0/32 proxy port ftp ftp/tcp
map em0 0/0                     -> 0/32 portmap tcp/udp auto
map em0 0/0                     -> 0/32

# Redirect direct web traffic to local web server.
rdr em0  192.168.0.3/32 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 80 tcp
rdr bge0 192.168.1.3/32 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 80 tcp
# Redirect everything else to squid on port 3128 or 3129 intercept
rdr em0  0.0.0.0/0 port 80      -> 127.0.0.1 port 3128 tcp
rdr bge0 0.0.0.0/0 port 80      -> 127.0.0.1 port 3128 tcp
#rdr em0  0.0.0.0/0 port 80     -> 127.0.0.1 port 3129 tcp
#rdr bge0 0.0.0.0/0 port 80     -> 127.0.0.1 port 3129 tcp
```

With 3128 is OK, but with 3129, Does not work, when switch in ipnat.rules.

Comment: Check http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the ancient, antiquated, abandoned, and ailing IPFilter instead of IPFW or PF?

Comment: Thank´s @ott and @Chris for answering, I checked wiki and try with PF, IPFW, the problem is `http_port xxxx intercept` appears to be `BUG #3329: Orphan Comm::Connection:`

Answer (score 1):

You really want to be using pf with intercept under Freebsd - http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/FreeBsdPf.

We have successfully got tproxy to work because of a requirement to use ipfw, but it required kernel changes (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4).